Ubuntu server 20.04 does not initialize systemd script!
I'm trying to put a script to run at Ubuntu startup via systemd, but the same error occurs and the command is not executed, the script is used to raise the tap interface, and make the bridge with the br0 interface, the following is the content of the script:
/usr/local/bin/tap.sh
#!/bin/bash
ip link set tap0 up &
brctl addif br0 tap0 &
wait
echo "finish"
When I run the script manually it works and the tap0 interface starts, but when I try to go up through systemd at startup I get the following error:
tap.service - TAP Interface
Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/tap.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: inactive (dead) since Wed 2024-05-22 15:15:06 UTC; 5min ago
Process: 860 ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/tap.sh (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Main PID: 860 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
May 22 15:15:05 srvvpn systemd[1]: Starting TAP Interface...
May 22 15:15:06 srvvpn tap.sh[868]: Cannot find device "tap0"
May 22 15:15:06 srvvpn tap.sh[869]: interface tap0 does not exist!
May 22 15:15:06 srvvpn tap.sh[860]: comandos finalizados
May 22 15:15:06 srvvpn systemd[1]: tap.service: Succeeded.
May 22 15:15:06 srvvpn systemd[1]: Finished TAP Interface.***
here is the content of the tap.service service file:
/etc/systemd/system/tap.service
[Unit]
Description=TAP Interface
After=network-online.target
[Service]
Type=oneshot
User=root
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/tap.sh
[Install]
WantedBy=network-online.target**
I thank the help of all!!!

What creates the tap?

what creates the TAP is the openvpn configuration.

That sounds more and more like an XYProblem. Either way, obviously at the very least you'll need to (if you for whatever reason insist on going down this way) make the service wait until the tap is created, as the error suggested. One way is to order it after the OpenVPN service (assuming you are using one). Another way is to make the service wanted by the device unit of the tap.

Exactly, the service would have to go up after creating the tap0 interface, would you have a suggestion on how I would configure the service to start after the start of openvpn?

problem solved, a parameter was missing in my openvpn server.conf: --script-security 2, without this parameter openvpn cannot execute external scripts, everything works now, Thanks for the help.
